# How to obtain two most recent encounter dates?

Tags: max, cognos, appointment

I have used this expression in Cognos `[Encounter Date]=maximum([Encounter Date] for [Patient Account Number])` to obtain the most recent visit. Does anyone know a command for two most recent visits?

Answer (score 0):

Create a data item that ranks `[Encounter Date] for [Patient Account Number]`
Set the filter where `[Rank] <= 2`
Remember the filter should be AFTER aggregation (not the default before aggregation)